# Banker or Bunker?

Tags: dialogue, fargo-tv

During the dialogue between Emmit Stussy and V.M. Varga in Emmit's study in the *Fargo* season 3 episode "The Narrow Escape Problem", Varga lectures him on wealth and says something like

> It's a banker in Wyoming and another in Gstaad.

I also searched online for transcripts and the [one I was able to find](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=fargo-2014&episode=s03e04) confirms this.

However, **I don't quite understand this dialogue. It seems to me like that should actually say "bunker" instead of "banker"**, since Varga also mentions "There's an accounting coming, Mr.Stussy" and "Mongol hordes descending" and "Now what are you doing to insulate yourself and your family?" right before that.

Could someone who has access to the official transcripts or subtitles (DVD/BluRay) confirm that he really says "banker" and **explain what he actually wants to say with that line** in this case?

Comment: Since they are talking about stockpiling money...why **wouldn't** they be talking about bankers?

Comment: Thank you. I refined it a little further into more of a dialogue explanation question rather than just a transcript lookup, since *that* seems to be what you're actually confused about to begin with. Seems like a reasonable question now. In general, please try to ask the actual question you're really interested in, since that often makes for a more engaging and fruitful experience for everyone involved, especially you as the asker.

Answer (score 4):

It is confirmed by the French subtitles of Netflix:

> C'est un **banquier** dans le Wyoming et un autre à Gstaad.

And by the French dubs from Netflix:

> C'est un **banquier** ...

and by the English subtitles

> It's a **banker** in Wyoming and another in Gstaad.

Then,

- [**Gstaad**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gstaad) is a well known snow resort in Switzerland where highly rich people like to go. Switzerland is also known as a [tax heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_haven).
- Wyoming his considered as a tax heaven and it has been revealed by Panama Papers that rich people might hide [money](https://www.wyomingpublicmedia.org/post/wyoming-involved-panama-papers).

Being a banker working at these two places means that not only being probably rich, a banker would also be working with a lot amounts of rich people's money, and be talented in managing it and protect it from Money Enforcement.

Varga is warning Stussy about the incoming of Money Enforcement and as a "small rich", Emmit is not used to deal with them and doesn't have the backup to manage this situation.

Comment: Those are valid points. But the overall theme of Varga's speech was about being guarded. In addition to the quotes in my original post, he also says things like "... accumulation of wealth, not money, ... and using that wealth to become invisible" and "Rich is a fleet of private planes filled with decoys to mask your scent".  Given such a context, I believe, bunker would be more fitting than banker.

Comment: @Vectorizer, yes being guarded against Money Enforcement, since when you earn a lot of money, you'll attract attention of Money Enforcement services. A banker will help you manage this money, and turn it into wealth (investments, companies, real estate, etc) instead of just staking money in a bank account.

Comment: @Vectorizer If you're so intent on sticking to your ***incorrect*** interpretation, why do you even bother asking here? Your comment here even contradicts ***your own question***, in which you state: "Varga lectures him on wealth". Now you claim "Varga's speech was about being guarded", simply because you don't like the answer. The ***fact*** is that the word he used is "banker", and it perfectly fits because he is saying that being wealthy means you can afford bankers in multiple known tax havens.

Comment: @Vectorizer Here's a famous routine by Chris Rock on the same topic of being rich vs being wealthy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeOUty4SWvI

Comment: @BCdotWEB: While I appreciate the contributions, I have asked "Could someone who has access to the official transcripts or subtitles (DVD/BluRay) confirm...". So far I have not received this.

Comment: @Vectorizer Netflix subtiles are not reliable enough for you? Unfortunately I don't have the Blu-ray or DVD... good luck.

Comment: @Vectorizer, are you still not believing me?